# Refresh fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, search

I have 2 tabs and each has one fragment. Each fragment has recycler views. I have an action bar and that have a search property in it (I'm using materialsearchview). I want to search the data in each fragment 
When my app is loading, the search is working for the first fragment, then if I swipe to the next fragment and come back to the first fragment the search is not working as because the methods related to the first fragment is not getting called. So how to call them when the user is in the first fragment.

```
    public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";
        Context c;
        String user_name,password;
        MaterialSearchView materialSearchView;
        String url = null;

        RecyclerView rv1;
        TableLayout tabLayout;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            setUserVisibleHint(false);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment,container,false);

            tabLayout=(TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
            final TableLayout tabLayout1=(TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
            final TableLayout tabLayout2=(TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout2);

            materialSearchView = (MaterialSearchView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("postman", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            user_name=sharedPreferences.getString("username","nothing");
            password=sharedPreferences.getString("password","nothing");


            rv1 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecycler1);


            rv1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
            rv1.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());




            Download2 d2 = new Download2(getActivity(),url,rv1,user_name,password,tabLayout,materialSearchView);

            d2.execute();

            return view;
        }

The other fragment is:

public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Tab3Fragment";

String user_name,password;
Context c;
MaterialSearchView materialSearchView3;
RecyclerView rv, rv1;
TableLayout tabLayout1 , tabLayout;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setUserVisibleHint(false);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_fragment,container,false);


    tabLayout1=(TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);


    materialSearchView3 = (MaterialSearchView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("postman", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user_name=sharedPreferences.getString("username","nothing");
    password=sharedPreferences.getString("password","nothing");

    rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecycler);


    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
    rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    return view;
}

@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    if(menuVisible)
    {
        Download3 d3 = new Download3(getActivity(),url,rv,user_name,password,tabLayout1, materialSearchView3);
        d3.execute();
    }

  }
 }
```

Comment: did you implement a interface with a listener on your fragments?

Comment: Sir, I'm new to android. Which interface are you telling?

Comment: Please post your relevant code so that the SO community can better help you.

Comment: Sir, I have uploaded the code. Please help me with my problem.

Comment: You don't need to refresh fragment, refresh the adapter of recycler view by: <your_adapter_name>.notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @ShivamArora Sir, can you specify the adapter name.